# How can I remove MARKETING flag in the subject using SENGDRID email service

Tags: email, twilio, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using Sendgrid email provider in my app and for some reason MARKETING flag is added as a subject.
I must say that this is the case just when I use specific email address with my domain.
So if my domain is **example.com** and my email address is: **myemail@example.com** as a sender then the subject is flagged. For every other email address under **example.com** this is not a problem. See the pic:

[image]